# Difference between MatLab and Octave function cp2tform

Tags: matlab, octave, transformation

I have a function [cp2tform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/cp2tform.html) in MatLab. I presume that a function [cp2tform](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/cp2tform.html) in Octave, is supposed to give the same output as the one in MatLab.

The problem is that in some cases the outputs are different.

---

**Example:**

**MatLab Code:**

```
A = [1,5; 8,7; 10,15];
B = [0,7; 0,4; 0,5];
cp2tform(A,B,'nonreflective similarity')
```

Output:

```
  -0.148848198464265  -0.305965741287655                   0
   0.305965741287655  -0.148848198464265                   0
  -1.810986414648551   8.610750147666863   1.000000000000000
```

**Octave code:**

```
A = [1,5; 8,7; 10,15];
B = [0,7; 0,4; 0,5];
cp2tform(A,B,"nonreflective similarity")
```

Output:

```
-0.05960  -0.12252   0.00000
 0.12252  -0.05960   0.00000
-0.72517   6.64570   1.00000
```

---

**My question**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess: using another function? The MATLAB code you put there uses `fitgeotrans` not `cp2tform`....

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you can not describe the transformation between your points using `'nonreflective similarity'`.

The correct answer is: both MATLAB and OCTAVE are wrong.

`'nonreflective similarity'`, from MATLAB:

> Use this transformation when shapes in the input image are unchanged,
>   but the image is distorted by some combination of translation,
>   rotation, and scaling. Straight lines remain straight, and parallel
>   lines are still parallel.

[image]

But if you look at your points:

[image]

There is no way you can convert a triangle into a line with rotation translation and scaling. Therefore, the computation fails.

Comment: I liked the part where you drew the free-handed red arrow and circle.

Comment: Plus 1 for the freehand.  However, if I may add how to correct this use a **projective** transformation, so replace `nonreflective similarity` to `projective` and you're good to go.